# Find repeated value based on count sub column value VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying count the subcolumn value based on main column duplicate value

My input is like below:

[image]

and I want output like this:

[image]

Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Looks like you're looking for [`COUNTIF`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34), and/or [`COUNTIFS`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842). A pivot table could also do that. How are you planning to solve the problem? "with VBA" is just too vague, especially in a scenario that doesn't need any code in the first place. What have you tried? Which part are you stuck on? Do you know how to write to and read from a `Range`?

Comment: i am not familiar formulas so far so i am trying to do with VBA Code.

Comment: And we can absolutely help with that, but we need a much more specific problem to help with - as it stands this is "I need XYZ, how do I do that with code?", ...which isn't too far off from "I need XYZ, can someone write it for me?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your "Open" column you should need this formula.

`=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$100,$B2,$D$2:$D$100,"Open")`

And this formula for your "Open" and "Medium" extract.

`=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$100,$B2,$C$2:$C$100,"Medium",$D$2:$D$100,"Open")`

In both formulas the upper limit of the criteria range is arbitrary. It makes almost no difference whether you define it as B100 or B1000 or even B:B. I just don't like the latter because to search through 1.4 million rows while I know that there will never be more than 100 seems like a waste of energy :-)